# How to return a C# Dataset to Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup

I have a C# dll that I'm calling from Inno Setup.  The function returns a DataSet.

I'm having a hard time figuring out what data type this would map to in Inno Setup.  It's been fairly easy calling and returning individual values, but I'm not sure how to return back an array of values (either an array of a type or an array of multiple types).

Is there a datatype that a dataset would directly map to in Inno or is there a better way for going about this?

Comment: Two hints. 1. you won't be able to import your library unless you'll use an extension like Unmanaged Exports (C# is not a good choice here). 2. you will need to use a COM friendly dataset object (into which you'll need to copy your `DataSet` object), like e.g. [`ADO Recordset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: What data are you trying to return for what reasons?